# How to name a controller file for uppercase table in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, uppercase

Hye. I want to make a controller and model for a table which is named in uppercase and abbreviation.

For example, the table name is PS_DEPT_TBL

1) What would be the controller file name? Is it PSDEPTTBL_controller.php? The code below seems to be not working for the controller.

```
class PSDEPTTBLController extends AppController {

    var $uses = 'PS_DEPT_TBL';
    var $scaffold ;

}
```

2) I name the model file as PSDEPTTBL.php and code it as below.

```
class PSDEPTTBL extends AppModel {

    var $useTable = 'PS_DEPT_TBL';

}
```

But the error shows that there isn't any controller of the table. I'm new to cakephp. Help me.

Comment: Assuming CakePHP 1.3, filenames are ALWAYS lowercase. See [naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/902/File-and-Classname-Conventions) in the CakePHP CookBook.
Also, your `$uses` array should NOT contain the name of the table but the classname of the Model that the controller uses. A `$uses` array is only necessary in case you want a controller to use a model that doesn't have a matching name (i.e. for BooksController and BookModel it's not needed, but it is for BooksController and DisasterModel).
I'd advise you to give your controller/model a readable name, and use `$useTable`

Comment: Thanks Joep for your response. I am using cakephp 2.05 for my application.

Comment: Has your problem been solved now?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Joep. It has been solved. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

There is **no need** for your controller to be called the same as your table. The same goes for your model.

How about something this:

```
// ThingsController.php
class ThingsController extends AppController
{
    var $uses = array('Thing');
}

// Thing.php
class Thing extends AppModel
{
    var $useTable = 'PS_DEPT_TBL';
}

// Config/routes.php
Router::connect(
    '/PSDEPTTBL/:action/*', array('controller' => 'things')
);
```

The key idea here is to make your code readable. If you have a legacy database, the best thing you can do for yourself is to hide it all in all the models.